# Error bars - how to calculate deviation using ratio between two samples

Tags: error

How should I calculate standard deviation if visualize results using ratio. I have two sets of samples: control and treatment. For each, there are four replicates. I would like to visualize it using ratio calculation on the mean. Then I performed T-test to find significant changes. However, I have no idea how to calculate standard deviation. There are four independent replicates for each of the sample so I have no idea how to get these error bars.

Lets say that's my data:

```
Control
1. Paul_1 - 2000
2. Paul_2 - 3000
3. Paul_3 - 2500
4. Paul_4 - 2000

Treatment
1. Paul1_1 - 3000
2. Paul1_2 - 3500
3. Paul1_3 - 1500
4. Paul1_4 - 3000
```